# Android navigation bar icons color

Tags: android, navigation, uinavigationbar

I tried to color my bottom navigation bar
In some android versions it's look white background with white icons

```
    protected void updateNavigationBarColor(Window window, boolean isLight) {
    if (window == null) {
        return;
    }

    View decorView = window.getDecorView();
    if (decorView == null) {
        return;
    }

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        window.setNavigationBarColor(Utils.getColor(R.color.navigation_bar_color));//black or white
        WindowInsetsControllerCompat controller = new WindowInsetsControllerCompat(window, decorView);
        controller.setAppearanceLightNavigationBars(isLight);
    } else {
        // Do nothing
    }
}
```

[image: Nav bar result after code run]

The navigation bar background color is exactly what I ask for. but the 3 buttons (icons) are stay in always light

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In themes.xml added to my theme

```
<item name="android:navigationBarColor">@color/transparent</item>
<item name="android:windowLightNavigationBar">true</item>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's my programmatial solution for changing color of navigation bar buttons to dark or light background.

```
    public static void setNavBarForeground(boolean light, Activity activity, View view){
    try {
        if (!light) {//make buttons dark to be more visible
            if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
                WindowInsetsController windowInsetController = activity.getWindow().getInsetsController();
                if (windowInsetController != null)
                    windowInsetController.setSystemBarsAppearance(WindowInsetsController.APPEARANCE_LIGHT_NAVIGATION_BARS, WindowInsetsController.APPEARANCE_LIGHT_NAVIGATION_BARS);
            } else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                view.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_NAVIGATION_BAR);
            }
        } else { //make buttons light to be more visible
            if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
                WindowInsetsController windowInsetController = activity.getWindow().getInsetsController();
                if (windowInsetController != null)
                    windowInsetController.setSystemBarsAppearance(0, WindowInsetsController.APPEARANCE_LIGHT_NAVIGATION_BARS);
            } else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                view.setSystemUiVisibility(0);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        Logger.log(e);
    }
}
```