# How can I keep or change the navigationBar color?

Tags: java, android, navigation, statusbar

I have developed an android application, there is a picture in the foreground. When I click on the picture, I make the background change (white if it is black, if it is black it will be white) at the same time I want to change the statusBarIcon color. and for that too

`getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_STATUS_BAR);`

I use. In this way, the color of the statusbar icons is gray exactly as I want, and then I want to change the color of the icons to white.

`getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(0);`

I am executing this command. everything is normal until here.. but when I do this, the color of the navigationBar icons also changes. How can I keep it or I want to change the color of the icons on the navigation bar

[image]

[image]

Comment: Maybe you can refer to this two answers about changing the color of icon in navigation bar. 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33104246/change-navigation-bar-icon-color-on-android, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70788078/android-navigation-bar-icons-color

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it inside styles.xml using

```
<item name="android:navigationBarColor">@color/theme_color</item>
```

If you want to do it in code use

[`window.setNavigationBarColor(@ColorInt int color)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Window.html#setNavigationBarColor(int))

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do in programmatically, then you have to select right method for different android version.
So here's my solution for this.

```
    public static void setNavBarForeground(boolean light, Activity activity, View view){
    try {
        if (!light) {//make buttons dark to be more visible
            if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
                WindowInsetsController windowInsetController = activity.getWindow().getInsetsController();
                if (windowInsetController != null)
                    windowInsetController.setSystemBarsAppearance(WindowInsetsController.APPEARANCE_LIGHT_NAVIGATION_BARS, WindowInsetsController.APPEARANCE_LIGHT_NAVIGATION_BARS);
            } else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                view.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_NAVIGATION_BAR);
            }
        } else { //make buttons light to be more visible
            if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
                WindowInsetsController windowInsetController = activity.getWindow().getInsetsController();
                if (windowInsetController != null)
                    windowInsetController.setSystemBarsAppearance(0, WindowInsetsController.APPEARANCE_LIGHT_NAVIGATION_BARS);
            } else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                view.setSystemUiVisibility(0);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        Logger.log(e);
    }
}
```